Create Concatenated Column With Values That Conditionally Match Fields for Same Encounter
Newbie here. I'm sure the answer is out there, but I don't know what to look for...
See example table I am dealing with - I have multiple numbered items under the same encounter, where some of the items where tagged (Tag 1, Tag 2, etc.). All non-tagged item numbers are marked as paired, since they were on the same encounter as a tagged item. Each item number has a dollar amount returned and a corresponding HasReturn column.



Encounter
ItemNum
AType
Returned
HasReturn




12345
1
Paired
$0.00
No


12345
2
Paired
$0.00
No


12345
3
Tag1
$200.00
Yes


12345
4
Paired
$0.00
No


12345
5
Paired
$0.00
No


12345
6
Tag2
$0.00
No


12345
7
Paired
$0.00
No


12345
8
Paired
$159.49
Yes


12345
9
Paired
$159.49
Yes


12345
10
Paired
$0.00
No


12345
11
Paired
$35.25
Yes


12345
12
Paired
$0.00
No


12345
13
Paired
$0.00
No


12345
14
Paired
$26.44
Yes


12345
15
Paired
$7.55
Yes


12345
16
Paired
$0.00
No


12345
17
Paired
$4,391.74
Yes


12345
18
Paired
$0.00
No



I am trying to get to the following end result - where I am displaying all the rows with a positive return value, but I also need to add a 'PrimaryTag' column that shows all ATypes present on that Encounter (concatenated), regardless of whether than line had a return value above $0 or not.



Encounter
ItemNum
AType
PrimaryTag
Returned




12345
3
Tag1
Tag1, Tag2
$200.00


12345
8
Paired
Tag1, Tag2
$159.49


12345
9
Paired
Tag1, Tag2
$159.49


12345
11
Paired
Tag1, Tag2
$35.25


12345
14
Paired
Tag1, Tag2
$26.44


12345
15
Paired
Tag1, Tag2
$7.55


12345
17
Paired
Tag1, Tag2
$4,391.74



Please help me figure out what ??? needs to be.
select Encounter, ItemNum, AType, ??? AS PrimaryTag, Returned  from Table1
WHERE HasReturn = 'Yes'
Using Oracle PL/SQL if it matters. Thank you.

You could use LISTAGG() like this:
WITH dat AS
(
  SELECT '12345' AS Encounter, 1 AS ItemNum, 'Paired' AS Atype, '$0.00' AS returned, 'No' AS hasreturn FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 2, 'Paired', '$0.00', 'No'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 3, 'Tag1', '$200.00', 'Yes'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 4, 'Paired', '$0.00', 'No'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 5, 'Paired', '$0.00', 'No'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 6, 'Tag2', '$0.00', 'No'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 7, 'Paired', '$0.00', 'No'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 8, 'Paired', '$159.49', 'Yes'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 9, 'Paired', '$159.49', 'Yes'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 10, 'Paired', '$0.00', 'No'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 11, 'Paired', '$35.25', 'Yes'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 12, 'Paired', '$0.00', 'No'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 13, 'Paired', '$0.00', 'No'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 14, 'Paired', '$26.44', 'Yes'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 15, 'Paired', '$7.55', 'Yes'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 16, 'Paired', '$0.00', 'No'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 17, 'Paired', '$4,391.74', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345', 18, 'Paired', '$0.00', 'No'      FROM DUAL
)
SELECT dt.encounter
     , dt.itemnum
     , dt.atype
     , typs.PrimaryTag
     , dt.returned
  FROM dat dt    
       INNER JOIN (SELECT encounter, listagg(atype, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) AS PrimaryTag
                     FROM dat 
                    WHERE atype LIKE 'Tag%' 
                    GROUP BY encounter) typs ON  typs.encounter = dt.encounter 
 WHERE dt.hasreturn = 'Yes'
 ORDER BY dt.itemnum ASC;

this is just for demonstration purpose, I've created a WITH clause in order to create a sample and have disregarded most of the data types since we only care about the Atype and hasReturned.
